# Python Selenium accessing HTML source

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I get the [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) source in a variable using the Selenium module with Python?

I wanted to do something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://example.com")
if "whatever" in html_source:
    # Do something
else:
    # Do something else
```

How can I do this? I don't know how to access the HTML source.

Comment: Write following line before if condition:  html_source = browser.page_source

Answer (score 257):

You need to access the [`page_source`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=get_attribute#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) property:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://example.com")

html_source = browser.page_source
if "whatever" in html_source:
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

Comment: Best answer so far! The most immediate and clear way to do this, much more compact that the other, still valid, alternative (`find_element_by_xpath("//*").get_attribute("outerHTML")`(

Comment: What if we need to get page source after all the javascript executes.?

Comment: Works only if the page has completely loaded. If the page loads indefinitely this property doesn't work.

Answer (score 18):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
html_source_code = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")
html_soup: BeautifulSoup = BeautifulSoup(html_source_code, 'html.parser')
```

Now you can apply BeautifulSoup function to extract data...

Answer (score 8):

*driver.page_source* will help you get the page source code. You can check if the text is present in the page source or not.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("some url")
if "your text here" in driver.page_source:
    print('Found it!')
else:
    print('Did not find it.')
```

If you want to store the page source in a variable, add below line after *driver.get*:

```
var_pgsource=driver.page_source
```

and change the *if* condition to:

```
if "your text here" in var_pgsource:
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 5):

With Selenium2Library you can use `get_source()`

```
import Selenium2Library
s = Selenium2Library.Selenium2Library()
s.open_browser("localhost:7080", "firefox")
source = s.get_source()
```

Comment: Can I set a delay and get the latest source? There are dynamic contents loaded using javascript.

Answer (score 3):

By using the page source you will get the whole HTML code.
So first decide the block of code or tag in which you require to retrieve the data or to click the element..

```
options = driver.find_elements_by_name_("XXX")
for option in options:
    if option.text == "XXXXXX":
        print(option.text)
        option.click()
```

You can find the elements by name, XPath, id, link and CSS path.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about getting the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) to use for urllib, just execute this JavaScript code:

```
url = browser.execute_script("return window.location;")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `WebDriver` object, and access to the page source code via its `@property` field `page_source`...

Try this code snippet :-)

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox('path/to/executable')
driver.get('https://some-domain.com')
source = driver.page_source
if 'stuff' in source:
    print('found...')
else:
    print('not in source...')
```

Comment: how does this answer differs from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7866938/2231972 ?

Answer (score -7):

I'd recommend getting the source with [urllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) and, if you're going to parse, use something like [Beautiful Soup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup).

```
import urllib

url = urllib.urlopen("http://example.com") # Open the URL.
content = url.readlines() # Read the source and save it to a variable.
```

Comment: Okay then do you know how I can get the URL within Selenium? I want to store the URL in a variable so I can access it with urllib.

Comment: @user1008791 Does it matter? You're apparently letting the user type it in anyway using raw_input, just do the same but with urllib.

Comment: That was just to make an easy example, the URL will be changing a lot.

Comment: Selenium does many things that urllib doesn't (e.g. execution of JavaScript).

Comment: Using the urllib here is pointless, why? AutomatedTester has it correct, it is what I do for scanning through HTML source to make sure we don't push development environment code.