# I can't get the whole source code of an HTML page

Tags: python, web-crawler

Using Python, I want to crawl data on a web page whose source if quite big (it is a Facebook page of some user).

Say the URL is the URL I am trying to crawl. I run the following code:

```
import urllib2

usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = usock.read()
usock.close()
```

Data is supposed to contain the source of the page I am crawling, but for some reason, it doesn't contain all the characters that are available when I compare directly with the source of the page. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I know that the page I am trying to crawl has not been updated recently, so it is not due to the fact that I am missing some very recent data.

Does someone have a clue?

EDIT: the kind of information I am missing is like:

```
<code class="hidden_elem" id="up82eq_33"><!-- <div class="mbs profileInfoSection"><div class="uiHeader uiHeaderTopAndBottomBorder uiHeaderSection infoSectionHeader"><div class="clearfix uiHeaderTop"><div><h4 tabindex="0" class="uiHeaderTitle">Basic Information</h4></div></div></div><div class="phs"><table class="uiInfoTable mtm profileInfoTable uiInfoTableFixed"><tbody><tr><th class="label">Networks</th><td class="data"><div class="uiCollapsedList uiCollapsedListHidden" id="up82eq_32"><span class="visible">XXXX</span></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div> --></code>
```

It's basically some field I am interested in. What surprises me is that I can get *some* fields, but not all.

Comment: javascript is loading some content maybe and your crawler is not executing it?

Comment: have you checked the code charset?

Comment: @dyoser I did check the code charset, thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it's not the cause of my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Selenium accessing HTML source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861775/python-selenium-accessing-html-source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook is heavily Javascript orientated. The page source you see in the browser is the DOM *after* after any JS code has run (and the page source will frequently be changing anyway). You may have to automate a browser (using Selenium), or try other tools such as mechanize... Or look into a proper FB app and use the FB API.

Comment: I just tried with mechanize like that:

resp = mechanize.urlopen(url);
txt = resp.read()

But still the same problem...

Comment: @S4M May well just have to use Selenium then http://seleniumhq.org/ - Bear in mind data may not exist until certain user events occur (such as clicking items, or expanding menus)

Answer (score 2):

This page may execute some javascript and javascript generates some content.
Try [Twill](http://twill.idyll.org/).
It based on [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), but executes javascript.
Sample in Python:

```
from twill.commands import *
go("http://google.com/")
fv("f", "q", "test")
submit("btnG")
info() #shows page info
show() #shows html
```

Another option is to use [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) on Node.js.
This library works even better then Twill and it is browserless solution.
Sample in Coffeescript:

```
zombie = require "zombie"
browser = new zombie()
browser.visit "https://www.google.ru/", =>
    browser.fill "q", "node.js"
    browser.pressButton "Поиск в Google", ->
        for item in browser.queryAll "h3.r a"
            console.log item.innerHTML
```

Comment: I just tried Twill, but it's not working as well. In fact, I have even more info missing than with urllib2