# Get contents of entire page using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Using Selenium for browser automation (Python).

If I understand correctly, the following code would be used

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
the_text = inputElement.text
```

How would I go about getting the text on the whole page as opposed to looking within a particular element?

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_name('body').text`?

Comment: What if the HTML is malformed?

Comment: You're working with the DOM, not the HTML. Browsers are extremely lenient and will try to make sense of the HTML.

Comment: Ah ok. Will this not include the HEAD portion though?

Comment: It shouldn't. The `<head>` shouldn't be in the `<body>`.

Comment: I think this is *not* a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861775/python-selenium-accessing-html-source

Answer (score 66):

Looks like the entire page text can be found in:

```
driver.page_source
```