# Why are requests and urllib2 missing some text from webpages?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib2

The following code extracts webpage info

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.surfline.com/surf-report/rincon-southern-california_4197/'

source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
print plain_text

site = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
print site
```

Both libraries results include:

```
<div id="current-surf-range" style="font-size:21px;font-weight:bold;padding-top:7px; padding-bottom: 7px;"></div>
```

Unfortunately this is different from the actual webpage:

```
<div id="current-surf-range" style="font-size:21px;font-weight:bold;padding-top:7px; padding-bottom: 7px;">4-5ft</div>
```

**4-5ft** is not present and therefore cannot be extracted by BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Probably the data is loaded asynchronously after the `HTTP/1.1 200` response is sent back. PS. crawling data from websites is not always legal, check the licenses for the published data or look for a REST service providing similar data.

Comment: `requests` and `urllib2` are never going to execute the JavaScript. But I can show you solution in `selenium`.

Comment: @GeorgePetrov: please do

Comment: @boogie_bullfrog how it goes?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the `selenium`, full instruction in [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/installation.html#introduction).

> pip3 install selenium

2. Download drivers. I prefer to use [chrome driver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.20/), but if you have firefox installed, code below should work fine.

> ```
> from selenium import webdriver
> url = 'http://www.surfline.com/surf-report/rincon-southern-california_4197/'
> web = webdriver.Firefox()
> # web = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:9515', desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
>
> source_code = web.get(url)
> # Sometimes it take time to load the page that's why: from time import sleep; sleep(2)
> plain_text = source_code.page_source
> ```

Comment: I used `web = webdriver.Chrome()` instead.. 

Unfortunately, I get the error: 
_AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'page_source'_
with multiple sleep lengths. Also, it seems unreasonable to open a browser page and wait for it to load when scraping multiple pages.
Similar issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861775/python-selenium-accessing-html-source)