# getting '/img/empty.png' as response when scraping img src

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

i have a problem with extracting  from a dynamic car website:

```
def scrape(url):

    browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver') 
    browser.get(url) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
    
    cars = soup.find_all('article', class_='serp-item list')
    for car in cars:
        car_url = car.find('a')['href']
        img = car.img['src']
        print("IMG: " + img)
        print("URL: " + car_url)
```

for test reasons, first i printed the url which i want to download from but the img url goes like this `IMG: /img/empty.png` but the car_url is valid [Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPccH.png)

Tried scrolling whole page first but nothing achieved:

```
    # elem = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'serp-wrapper')
    # elem.click()
    # elem = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'serp-wrapper')
    # no_of_pagedowns = 10
    # while no_of_pagedowns:
    #     elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    #     time.sleep(0.2)
    #     no_of_pagedowns-=1
```

Comment: `page_source` seems to be the initial HTML without JavaScript modifications to the DOM. Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835835/987358 instead.